$L^2$ Fourier Inversion
I'm teaching Fourier analysis at a beginning graduate level.  To keep things simple, I defined the $L^2$ Fourier transform on say $\mathbb{R}$ to be $$\hat{f} (x) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-N} ^N e^{-2\pi i xy} f(y)$$ which is of course $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \widehat{f_N}$ where $f_N = \chi_{[-N,N]} f$ and $\widehat{f_N}$ is the standard $L^1$ Fourier transform.  Of course,  the idea here is that trivially  $f_N \in L^1 \cap L^2$ and $f_N \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$ (and so the convergence is trivially in $L^2$ by Fourier isometry for $L^1 \cap L^2$.)
I did prove that we could also define $\hat{f} =  \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \widehat{f_N}$ for $\textit{any}$ sequence $\{f_N\}_{N = 1}^\infty \subset L^1 \cap L^2$ where $f_N \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$ and arrive at the same $L^2$ function (really ``class")
Virtually every property for this $L^2$ Fourier transform is easy to prove using properties of the Fourier transform for functions in $L^1 \cap L^2$ (like Fourier isometry), but Fourier inversion is slightly more involved, as $\hat{f} \not \in L^1$ is  possible if $f$ is bounded and supported in an interval (for example the Fourier transform of $f(x) = \chi_{[-N, N]}$ is $\hat{f}(x) = \frac{\sin 2\pi N x}{\pi x} \not \in L^1$.  )
So it seems the simplest way to do this is pick $f_N \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$ where $f_N \in \mathcal{S} $ where $\mathcal{S}$ is the Schwartz space so that $\widehat{f_N} \in \mathcal{S} \subset L^1$ so that Fourier inversion is true for $f_N$.  But this means I need another lecture on the Schwartz space and its relation to the Fourier transform.
Or is there a simpler way?

Instead of using the Schwartz space explicitly, you could just show that the set of functions $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$ with $\hat{f} \in L^1 \cap L^2$ is dense. Something like $C_c^2(\mathbb{R})$ should do, no?

Yea that might be quicker, thanks!

Agreed with @Klaus that it can be done that way. But do you have a particular reason to avoid Schwartz space? It's pretty important after all...

Gyu: It is, and in fact this is a nice way to motivate the Schwartz space.  Basically I "proved" $L^2$ Fourier inversion as described above and forgot that $\widehat{f_N} \not \in L^1$ is very possible.  I did tell my class we'll return to this technicality later, so probably just putting it off until a lecture on the Schwartz space is best.
Lots more stuff for me to do (solving the heat equation via Fourier transforms, applications to QM, Poisson summation, Sampling theorem, FFT, Image compression, theory of Wavelets, Kernel ridge regression/Fourier Features, so it's really a time issue!
